# Python: get the element-wise mean of multiple arrays in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean, elementwise-operations

I have a 16x10 panda dataframe with 1x35000 arrays (or NaN) in each cell. I want to take the element-wise mean over rows for each column.

```
      1       2       3       ...       10
1    1x35000 1x35000 1x35000           1x35000

2    1x35000 NaN     1x35000           1x35000

3    1x35000 NaN     1x35000           NaN

...

16   1x35000 1x35000 NaN               1x35000
```

To avoid misunderstandings: take the first element of each array in the first column and take the mean. Then take the second element of each array in the first column and take the mean again. In the end I want to have a 1x10 dataframe with one 1x35000 array each per column. The array should be the element-wise mean of my former arrays.

```
      1       2       3       ...       10
1    1x35000 1x35000 1x35000           1x35000
```

Do you have an idea to get there elegantly preferably without for-loops?

Comment: Given the mixed dtype data (with NaN), I think performing mean for each cell iteratively might be the way to go here.

Comment: I hoped to avoid for-loops though :p

Comment: Check out the two vectorized solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46248304/3293881) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed([3,14159])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3, 5)).tolist(),
    list('XYZ'), list('ABC')
).applymap(np.array)

df.loc['X', 'B'] = np.nan
df.loc['Z', 'A'] = np.nan

df
```

---

```
                 A                B                C
X  [4, 8, 1, 1, 9]              NaN  [8, 2, 8, 4, 9]
Y  [4, 3, 4, 1, 5]  [1, 2, 6, 2, 7]  [7, 1, 1, 7, 8]
Z              NaN  [9, 3, 8, 7, 7]  [2, 6, 3, 1, 9]
```

---

**Solution**

```
g = df.stack().groupby(level=1)
g.apply(np.sum, axis=0) / g.size()

A                        [4.0, 5.5, 2.5, 1.0, 7.0]
B                        [5.0, 2.5, 7.0, 4.5, 7.0]
C    [5.66666666667, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.66666666667]
dtype: object
```

If you insist on the shape you presented

```
g = df.stack().groupby(level=1)
(g.apply(np.sum, axis=0) / g.size()).to_frame().T

                           A                          B                                              C
0  [4.0, 5.5, 2.5, 1.0, 7.0]  [5.0, 2.5, 7.0, 4.5, 7.0]  [5.66666666667, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.66666666667]
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! Very smart thoughts! I have two follow up questions if I may? First, I don't really understand what `groupby(level=1)` is doing - if I print `g` after this step it only shows `<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x000000F86E0A4940>`, could you elloborate on that? Second, `g.mean(axis = 0)` should do the same as `g.apply(np.sum, axis=0) / g.size()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 : Loopy**

Given the mixed dtype input data, we might want to loop through for performance efficiency. So, looping with explicit loops or *under-the-hood* usages of `.apply/.applymap` would be the solutions that could be suggested.

Here's one way looping through columns -

```
mask = ~df.isnull().values
n = df.shape[1]
out = np.empty((1,n),dtype=object)
for i in range(n):
    out[0,i] = df.iloc[mask[:,i],i].mean()
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [326]: df
Out[326]: 
              0             1             2
0  [4, 0, 1, 6]  [4, 2, 2, 2]  [5, 3, 5, 4]
1           NaN  [0, 5, 6, 8]           NaN
2           NaN           NaN           NaN
3           NaN           NaN           NaN

In [327]: df_out
Out[327]: 
                      0                     1                     2
0  [4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 6.0]  [2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0]  [5.0, 3.0, 5.0, 4.0]
```

---

**Approach #2 : Vectorized**

If you have to vectorize, here's one way using `matrix-multiplication` to replace the `mean-reductions` and that could bring about improvements for large data -

```
mask = ~df.isnull().values
v = np.vstack(df.values[mask])
r,c = np.where(mask)
n = df.shape[1]
pos_mask = c == np.arange(n)[:,None]
out = pos_mask.dot(v)/np.bincount(c).astype(float)[:,None]
df_out1 = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Sample output -

```
In [328]: df_out1
Out[328]: 
     0    1    2    3
0  4.0  0.0  1.0  6.0
1  2.0  3.5  4.0  5.0
2  5.0  3.0  5.0  4.0
```

**Approach #3 : Vectorized one more**

Making use of `np.add.reduceat` to get those `mean-reductions` -

```
mask = ~df.T.isnull().values
v = np.vstack(df.values.T[mask])
count = mask.sum(1)
out0 = np.add.reduceat(v, np.r_[0,count.cumsum()[:-1]])
out = out0/count[:,None].astype(float)
df_out2 = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort Divakar! There seem to be many solutions to the problem. I think I'll use piRSquared's answer, It's a bit shorter and pretty easy to understand.