# Python: how to get element-wise standard deviation of multiple arrays in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, standard-deviation, elementwise-operations

I have a rather big dataframe (df) containing arrays and NaN in each cell, the first 3 rows look like this:

```
df:
                 A                B                C
X  [4, 8, 1, 1, 9]              NaN  [8, 2, 8, 4, 9]
Y  [4, 3, 4, 1, 5]  [1, 2, 6, 2, 7]  [7, 1, 1, 7, 8]
Z              NaN  [9, 3, 8, 7, 7]  [2, 6, 3, 1, 9]
```

I already know [(thanks to piRSquared)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247854/python-get-the-element-wise-mean-of-multiple-arrays-in-a-dataframe) how to take the element-wise mean over rows for each column so that I get this:

```
element_wise_mean:
A                        [4.0, 5.5, 2.5, 1.0, 7.0]
B                        [5.0, 2.5, 7.0, 4.5, 7.0]
C    [5.66666666667, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.66666666667]
```

Now I wonder how to get the respective standard deviation, any idea? Also, I don't understand yet what groupby() is doing, could someone explain its function in more detail?

---

**df**

```
np.random.seed([3,14159])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3, 5)).tolist(),
    list('XYZ'), list('ABC')
).applymap(np.array)

df.loc['X', 'B'] = np.nan
df.loc['Z', 'A'] = np.nan
```

**element_wise_mean**

```
df2               = df.stack().groupby(level=1)
element_wise_mean = df2.apply(np.mean, axis=0)
```

**element_wise_sd**

```
element_wise_sd   = df2.apply(np.std, axis=0)
TypeError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Try on numpy array values - `df2.apply(lambda x: np.std(x.values))`?

Comment: I know somebody who would be very happy to see your seed value.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is that pirsquared?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ah sorry, I'm still new and not aware of conventions here, I'll make a reference :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying np.std using lambda with converting to `numpy array` is working for me :

```
element_wise_std = df2.apply(lambda x: np.std(np.array(x), 0))
#axis=0 is by default, so can be omit
#element_wise_std = df2.apply(lambda x: np.std(np.array(x)))
print (element_wise_std)
A                            [0.0, 2.5, 1.5, 0.0, 2.0]
B                            [4.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.5, 0.0]
C    [2.62466929134, 2.16024689947, 2.94392028878, ...
dtype: object
```

Or solution from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278161/python-how-to-get-element-wise-standard-deviation-of-multiple-arrays-in-a-dataf/46278283#comment79519281_46278161):

```
element_wise_std = df2.apply(lambda x: np.std(x.values, 0))
print (element_wise_std)
A                            [0.0, 2.5, 1.5, 0.0, 2.0]
B                            [4.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.5, 0.0]
C    [2.62466929134, 2.16024689947, 2.94392028878, ...
dtype: object
```

I try explain more:

First reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - columns are added to `index` and `Multiindex` is created.

```
print (df.stack())
X  A    [4, 8, 1, 1, 9]
   C    [8, 2, 8, 4, 9]
Y  A    [4, 3, 4, 1, 5]
   B    [1, 2, 6, 2, 7]
   C    [7, 1, 1, 7, 8]
Z  B    [9, 3, 8, 7, 7]
   C    [2, 6, 3, 1, 9]
dtype: object
```

Then `groupby(level=1)` means group by first level of `Multiindex` - (by values `A`, `B`, `C`) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) some function. Here it is `np.std`.

Pandas not working with `array`s or lists very nice, so converting is necessary. (It looks like bug)

Comment: A pandas column is a sequence, and in this case each sequence is an array. It looks like the pandas implementation is not playing nice with using this sequence of arrays. By doing `x.values` or `np.array(x)` the column is explicitly converted to a 2D array and so it works thereafter. Weird it works with `mean` and not `std` - would probably raise an issue on the pandas github to see what else could be going on

Comment: @KenSyme - Nice idea - I post it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17571).

Comment: Amazing thanks! It is counter intuitive to me that np.mean nd np.std should behave differently on the same dataset, but it really works this way. Would love to hear from you again once you hear why it is like that.

Answer (score 2):

Jezrael beat me to this:

To answer your question about `.groupby()`, try `.apply(print)`.  You'll see what is returned, and made to be used in `apply` functions:

```
df2 = df.stack().groupby(axis=1) #groups by the second index of df.stack()
df2.apply(print)
X  A    [4, 8, 1, 1, 9]
Y  A    [4, 3, 4, 1, 5]
Name: A, dtype: object
Y  B    [1, 2, 6, 2, 7]
Z  B    [9, 3, 8, 7, 7]
Name: B, dtype: object
X  C    [8, 2, 8, 4, 9]
Y  C    [7, 1, 1, 7, 8]
Z  C    [2, 6, 3, 1, 9]
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Conversely, try:

```
df3 = df.stack().groupby(level=0) #this will group by the first index of df.stack()
df3.apply(print)
X  A    [4, 8, 1, 1, 9]
   C    [8, 2, 8, 4, 9]
Name: X, dtype: object
Y  A    [4, 3, 4, 1, 5]
   B    [1, 2, 6, 2, 7]
   C    [7, 1, 1, 7, 8]
Name: Y, dtype: object
Z  B    [9, 3, 8, 7, 7]
   C    [2, 6, 3, 1, 9]
Name: Z, dtype: object
```

Comment: .apply(print) was exactly what I needed to visualize what is going on, thanks a bunch!